# Анимация jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста найти ошибку в JavaScript коде.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('gallery img').hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }.400);
        }.function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.5
            }.400);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: зяпятую вместо точки поставьте

Comment: И ошибки лучше смотрель в консоли допустим firebug'a у мозиллы, а то вы так будете каждый раз на форум писать.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что человек написавший этот код пишет его в блокноте. Нормальный редактор бы сразу подсветил ошибку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас это jquery? Если да, то

```
$('gallery img')
```

gallery - это класс или id? Если класс, то селектор .gallery, если id, то #gallery

```
animate({opacity: 1}. 400)
```

аргументы функции разделяются запятой, а не точкой
в общем, это все как-то так должно выглядеть

```
$(function(){
$('.gallery img').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
},
function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, 400);
    });
});
```